# How do you handle iOS 'Ask app not to track' popup in Browserstack?

Tags: ios, appium, ui-automation, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I'm using Appium with Python.

As the title says - how do you guys handle this system pop up in browserstack? I know of the capability "autoAcceptAlerts": true and then it does the job but the problem is that there are other system-like popups in my app that I'd like to decline ocassionally (depending on the test scenario) and most of the time I prefer to handle all the popups on my own but this specific one is unpredictable - I don't know when it's going to pop up or not.
[image]

I'm curious what's been your approach.